# Calendar cannot be updated on iPhone 6sPlus

Tags: calendar

After iOS 9.3.5 update installed, I lost the ability to add events in my calendar. How can I restore this capability?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. It would help us if you provided additional info, such as the types of devices, what you've tried to fix the problem, etc. Please see [ask] for how to ask good questions that have a better chance at being answered. - From Review -

Answer (score 1):

Go into Settings then Mail, Contacts, Calendars. Scroll down to Contacts, open Default Account. Select iCloud. 
Done.

Answer (score -1):

After iOS 9.3.5 update installed, I lost the ability to add events in my calendar. After following every suggestion I could find here on this site and online, nothing worked. So I just started turning features related to the calendar and iCloud on and off. One by one I checked to see if anything I did affected the calendar. Nothing did. So I kept going. And found my fix: Go into Settings then Mail, Contacts, Calendars. Scroll down to Contacts, open Default Account. Select iCloud. That's it. That was my necessary fix. Hope this helps someone else out there!